# Winforms Databinding to a specific element in array or list

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a BindingSource with an object inside bound to my controls. The form has a lot of textboxes generated at runtime from a list. The simplified code goes like this:

```
public class MyClassname: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // some more properties here ...
    public BindingList<string> mylist{ get; set; }
}
// ...
public MyClassname myclassname = new MyClassname();
private BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
// ...
bs.DataSource = typeof(myclassname);
bs.Add(myclassname);
// ...
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "mylist[2]");
```

I get the following error:

> DataMember property "mylist[2]" cannot be found on the DataSource

I already tried more types like dictionary, array or list and tried to access it in various ways without any success.

If I bind directly to the element like this:

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myclassname.mylist[2], "");
```

It works, but the binding is one way only. (won't update the the textbox when modified elsewhere)

P.S. The other members are accessed properly, even with nested objects.

Comment: Hi did you find a solution for that problem? I try to do the same thing by using DevExpress LayoutControl and I also create the controls dynamically.

Comment: I tried your "working" sample but it doesn't update the value of the list after changing the text in the textbox. The binding seems to be the same like textBox.Text = items[0]; without any chance to update the value.

Comment: @Verarind Hi I searched the web for weeks and tried a million things. In the end I had to use the direct binding mentioned in my post, loosing the features of a BindingSource. For this to work you will need to use a BindingList or implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface described [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) If you use the regular List it will be one way only.

Comment: Thx for the hint. I'm implementing and BindingMediator that manages the binding and registers for PropertyChanged and so on.

Answer (score 0):

its because myList doenst have item and cant find index#2 .
try adding to your BindingList something like:

```
mylist.Add(new BindingList{
//itemList = value;
});
```

and call index something like:

```
mylist[0];
```

Take note that index[] are depends on count of the list .

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply, and sorry if I was not clear. mylist is filled up with data before I try to bind. That's why I said it works if I try to bind it directly without using the bindingsource.